# scroll script given this error ----> TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, button, woocommerce

this is my jscript

```
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("button").on('click', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#button").offset().top
                }, 1000);


        });
    });
    </script>
```

this is my custom button

```
 <button name="button" style="margin: 9px 0 20px 0;padding: 3px 25px; background-color: red;color: white;font-weight: bold;" value="OK" type="button" >HAVE A QUESTIONS</button>
```

and this is scroll bottom location (to scroll top button to this location)

```
<!-- Have Question -->
<div class="content-teaser container text-center">
    <h3 class="text-red center-block text-center"  id="button" >Have Questions?</h3>
    <p>Talk with someone on the team We're here
to answer question</p>
```

all is work well but console put this error

TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

what is this error i can't understand plz solved this error because this error conflict to other script and my page doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this jQuery error..............

```
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("button").on('click', function(event) {

            var target = $("#button");

            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }

        });
    });
    </script>
```

in this way ADD TO CART button work & all jQuery work properly on this page

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#button").offset().top
```

Need to be:-

```
$("button").offset().top // or $(this).offset().top
```

***Note:-*** You can add `id="button"` to your button also (if you want to make your own code work fine).

Comment: but my scroll button id is                                                                          <!-- Have Question -->
<div class="content-teaser container text-center">
 <h3 class="text-red center-block text-center"  id="button" >Have Questions?</h3>
 <p>Talk with someone on the team We're here
to answer question</p>

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

remove `#`

```
$("button").offset().top // or $(this).offset().top
```

**solution 2**

add `id="button"`

```
<button id="button" name="button" style="margin: 9px 0 20px 0;padding: 3px 25px; background-color: red;color: white;font-weight: bold;" value="OK" type="button" >HAVE A QUESTIONS</button>
```

Comment: i do change both but my scroll don't work on this button(Have Question)

Comment: You don't need to do both. choose one solution and its will works